# How to send notification in Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api

Is there a way to send some kind of notification to a user that approved my Facebook app?

Or only posting on wall is possible?

tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to send private messages any longer; Facebook appear to have blocked the functionality due to abuse/spam etc. My suggestion would be to post to their wall, like you said, which would notify them anyway. That was our solution the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail